# TypeScript filter array by element name

Tags: typescript

My model array looks like:

```
 records: [{
            "idPartner": 2,
            "name": "partner1",
            "orgAddress1": "",
            "orgAddress2": null,
            "city": "Dorval",
            "postCode": "H9P 2V4",
            "state": "QC",
            "country": "CA",
            "province": null,
            "description": null
        },
        {
            "idPartner": 3,
            "name": "partner12",
            "orgAddress1": "",
            "orgAddress2": null,
            "city": "Dorval",
            "postCode": "H9P 2V4",
            "state": "QC",
            "country": "CA",
            "province": null,
            "description": null
        }
]
```

I need to create a new array with names only like `["partner1", "partner12"]`

How do I do that using typescript?

Comment: `[{partner1,partner2...}]` --- this is not valid syntax. But you probably need just to iterate over this array and fill another array. 1. `for` 2. `Array#push`

Comment: Yeah you right, just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you 2 solutions.

## Map

```js
records = [{
    "idPartner": 2,
    "name": "partner1",
    "orgAddress1": "",
    "orgAddress2": null,
    "city": "Dorval",
    "postCode": "H9P 2V4",
    "state": "QC",
    "country": "CA",
    "province": null,
    "description": null
  },
  {
    "idPartner": 3,
    "name": "partner12",
    "orgAddress1": "",
    "orgAddress2": null,
    "city": "Dorval",
    "postCode": "H9P 2V4",
    "state": "QC",
    "country": "CA",
    "province": null,
    "description": null
  }
]

console.log(records.map(x => x.name))
```

## Array.from()

As second option, use `Array.from` and return the `name`. It will create and array with only `name`.

```js
records = [{
    "idPartner": 2,
    "name": "partner1",
    "orgAddress1": "",
    "orgAddress2": null,
    "city": "Dorval",
    "postCode": "H9P 2V4",
    "state": "QC",
    "country": "CA",
    "province": null,
    "description": null
  },
  {
    "idPartner": 3,
    "name": "partner12",
    "orgAddress1": "",
    "orgAddress2": null,
    "city": "Dorval",
    "postCode": "H9P 2V4",
    "state": "QC",
    "country": "CA",
    "province": null,
    "description": null
  }
]

console.log(Array.from(records, (obj)=>{return obj.name}))
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for `Array.from` or the whole curly braces mess:

```
records.map(x => x.name);
```